# Визуалиция одномерного массива

Tags: python, matplotlib

Допустим, есть некоторый массив `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Вопрос, можно ли его как-то визуализировать на одной прямой? То есть, есть числовая прямая, и нужно на ней выделить точки (числа в массиве)?

Comment: Построить график точек с координатами (x, 0), где x - числа из массива.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [12]: x = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [13]: plt.hlines(0, xmin=min(x)-1, xmax=max(x)+1)
Out[13]: <matplotlib.collections.LineCollection at 0x285dee7def0>

In [14]: plt.scatter(x, [0] * len(x), c="orange", s=50)
Out[14]: <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x285dee0c860>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]